# Problem with cache, plugin Litespeed, server Litespeed and optimization

Tags: wordpress, caching, optimization, litespeed

I have been using the wordpress Litespeed plugin on my site Trailer y Estrenos CO. I have the Chemicloud hosting and it uses the Litespeed server, which according to them, it works super well if is used with the plugin of the same name.

On top of that, you started using Cloudflare and I integrated it into the Litespeed plugin.

My problem is the following:

When I measure how optimized the page is after having installed everything mentioned, in GTmetrix at the beginning it gives me a statistic of the B and C range, but soon after in another scan they lower me to C and D.

In the Litespeed plugin I have DNS Prefetch configured and in the first scan of range B and C the DNS Prefetch configuration works as it is, but in the others scans later that go down to ranges C and D, it seems that the DNS Prefetch does not work, since it shows me those external DNS errors.

I don't know if it's my ideas, but it seems that the Litespeed plugin didn't do its job well, although it could be other things.

Should I use another cache plugin? I know that the WP Rocket is very good but the detail is that it is paid.

Any suggestion or help?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible to append both GTMetrix B-C and C-D screenshots?

Comment: See the edited post

Comment: Great. I assume you are still having the dns-prefetch function On, so I just tested 4 times on the GTmetrix + Canada region and got the same result all the time. Same result here I mean B-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [current report](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/trailersyestrenos.co/ThndFaAz), Your scores are mainly dependent on your third-party resources. Everything that is loading from your domain(Litespeed) is pretty quick(Check the Waterfall section). If you expand the results which are causing these scores, you'll see the responsible ones.

Pagespeed Scores

- **Minimize Redirects** is caused by resources from addthis.com,openx.com and soon.
- **Leverage Browser Caching** is also by addthis, google and Facebook resources.
- **Serve Scaled Images** is something to be done during the upload, or a plugin like Shortpixel Adaptive Images can help you.

YSlow Scores

- **Add Expires Headers** is the same as Leverage Browser caching above.
- **Use a CDN** is caused by the same Third-Party Resources.
- **Use Cookie-Free Subdomains** is caused by Cloudflare, since it [appends its Cookies](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170156-Understanding-the-Cloudflare-Cookies) on all requests, but if your server is far away from where your visitors are, the benefits of using Cloudflare overweighs the drawbacks.
- **Reduce DNS Lookups** is again due to a lot of third-party resources, from multiple domains, DNS Prefetch can help the users resolve the DNS faster, but won't affect the scores.
- **Avoid URL Redirects** is the same as Minimize Redirects above.

No Cache plugin can edit how third-party requests are being handled by the website, while they can defer the requests or load them after the actual page is loaded to improve user experience, it won't still affect the scores.

**What should you do to fix these?**

- Figure out what you want to keep and remove the rest if not required.
- Talk to your developer about storing these external files locally so that they can be optimized and controlled using Litespeed Cache or any other Cache Plugin.
- For the `Minimize Redirects`, get in touch with the provider you're serving these resources from and ask them to improve this behavior.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it is a good report. I have a doubt, I saw that the plugin Addthis is a problem and I also heard that it is able to put slow the website, so Should I change that plugin ? Are there others more lighter ?

Comment: I think that is really a website-based question, I am not sure what other plugins are there for this that will meet your exact requirements, so feel free to try other plugins and let us all know here if you find an optimized one :)